# What is the right App Domain to input in developers.facebook.com now that i deployed my project in heroku?

Tags: django, facebook, heroku

I deployed my django project on heroku and my project have facebook login. And now that my project is deployed to a webhost it now has a domain name given by heroku.

The website name looks like this since I'm using their free service.
https://mywebsite.herokuapp.com

I tried to use that as App Domain in facebook developer site but everytime I tried logging in this is what facebook tells me.

Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

What is the right App Domain that I should input?

Comment: Did you set up the Website platform? Did you specify your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs?

Comment: yes the urls are working but it's still having errors